# Apache URL:port to URL

Tags: apache-2.2, redirection

I am trying to tidy up my server. I would like to use my web server as a front end only have port 80/443 open for admin.

I am focusing on services that are running on ports accessed by the Apache server.

I have a cups server running on www.example.com:631 and I want setup Apache to redirect to cups.example.com as I have a DNS entry for it. Do I use proxy, redirection/rewrite or do I use VirtualHost

Tried

```
<VirtualHost ??>
ServerName cups.example.com
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://cups.example.com:631
ProxyPassReverse / http://cups.example.com:631
</VirtualHost>
```

Any thoughts would be great, and I will summaries at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Apache for this. Apache is a HTTP server / proxy, and CUPS is not using HTTP protocol at all.

You can use other mechanisms like DNAT to redirect some other port to the CUPS port, but you cannot use the same port as Apache is using.